# How to implement Left or right outer join in QueryDsl

Tags: sql, outer-join, querydsl

How to implement  `Left` or `right outer join` in `QueryDsl`. A simple example is helpful.

Comment: Post your data or your query. Will be helpful to give you an exact solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28849713/querydsl-left-join-with-additional-conditions-in-on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836826/querydsl-how-to-make-left-join-by-column

Comment: Thanks, Prdp.    1) JPAQuery query = queryUtil.createJpaQuery()
  .from(t1).leftJoin(t1.t2, t2 ).on(t2.a.eq(t1.t2.a), how to change it to left outer join?  2) if 2 tables have no relationship, can they be jointed in QueryDsl?

Comment: @user1456650 - I don't know anything about `QueryDsl`. Did a google search and copy pasted results here

Comment: I did google search, all are about left join in QueryDsl, none is about outer join

Comment: According to the documentation, `leftJoin` and `rightJoin` are actually outer joins. The naming is quite confusing in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `leftJoin` method for that sake.
E.g.:

```
queryUtil
    .createJpaQuery()
    .from(t1)
    .leftJoin(t1.t2, t2)
    .fetchJoin()
    .where(t2.a.eq(t1.t2.a))
    .fetchAll()
```

Comment: But why? Why is there no "outerJoin" method in QDSL?

Comment: Please, refer to query dsl documentation: http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.2.2/reference/html/ch02.html, paragraph '2.1.7. Using joins'.